# Error in calling owl carousel in main js file

Tags: javascript, jquery, carousel, owl-carousel

I'm really new to coding especially JavaScript..
I can't seem to get Owl Carousel to work :(

when I'm saving my main.js file in Brackets I get a few errors:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".owl-carousel").owlCarousel();
});
```

The Errors:

```
 $' was used before it was defined. $(document).ready(function(){
1   
Expected exactly one space between 'function' and '('.  $(document).ready(function(){
1   
Expected exactly one space between ')' and '{'. $(document).ready(function(){
1   
Missing space between ')' and '{'.  $(document).ready(function(){
2   
Missing 'use strict' statement. $(".owl-carousel").owlCarousel();
```

I'm about to go crazy because I've included everything right and I don't have a fing clue what the errors mean...

here's my index.html

```
    <div class="owl-carousel">
      <div> Your Content </div>
      <div> Your Content </div>
      <div> Your Content </div>
      <div> Your Content </div>
      <div> Your Content </div>
      <div> Your Content </div>
      <div> Your Content </div>
    </div>



    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/owl.carousel.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
```

Please help, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

First of all please remove 2.2.4 and 1.12.4 jquery libraries. Secondly for main.js. Follow this code.

```
  $(".owl-carousel").owlCarousel({
    responsiveClass: true,
    dots: true,
    dotsContainer: false,
       loop: true,
       autoWidth: true,
      autoplay:true,
      nav:true,
      smartSpeed:1000,
      items:4,
      responsive: {
    0: {
      items:1,
      margin: 250,
      center: true

    },

    768: {
        items:3,
              margin:200,
         center: false
            },   

    992: {
        items:3,
    margin: 350,
        center: true
    },

    1200: {
          items:3,
        margin:350,
         center: true
    },

  },
  });
```

Add following CSS

```
.owl-nav {
    text-align: center;
        }
```

Then add owl.carousel.min.css in the style sheet

https://cdn.boomcdn.com/libs/owl-carousel/2.3.4/assets/owl.carousel.min.css"

[Demo link for working Responsive Owl Carousel at JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hilalrehan/vhg07k6s/20/)

You can add customise CSS and add changes accordingly. Please refer [Owl Carousel Documentation here](https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/docs/api-options.html)